# in elasticsearch, how to query for all documents where a date field is anytime Jan 1 2020 Pacific Time zone

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

in elasticsearch, how to query for all documents where a date field is anytime Jan 1 2020 Pacific Time zone. I just don't know how to specify Pacific time zone

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "version": true,
  "size": 500,
  "sort": [
    {
      "inserted_date": {
        "order": "desc",
        "unmapped_type": "boolean"
      }
    }
  ],
  "aggs": {
    "2": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "inserted_date",
        "fixed_interval": "30m",
        "time_zone": "America/Los_Angeles",
        "min_doc_count": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [],
      "filter": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "inserted_date": {
              "gte": "2019-12-31T18:30:00.000Z",
              "lte": "2020-01-01T18:29:59.000Z",
              "format": "strict_date_optional_time"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [],
      "must_not": []
    }
  }
}
```

This might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Pacific timezone can be mentioned either with IANA time zone or with UTC Offset value (If using this, take care of daylight savings)

UTC offset value

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "timestamp": {
        "time_zone": "-08:00",        
        "gte": "2020-01-01T00:00:00", 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

IANA time zone

```
GET /_search
    {
      "query": {
        "range": {
          "timestamp": {
            "time_zone": "America/Los_Angeles",        
            "gte": "2020-01-01T00:00:00", 
          }
        }
      }
    }
```